# I want to insert data into google fusion table from my android app database using java

Tags: java, android, google-fusion-tables

I am making an app in android where i am collecting data through form and saving it in the SQLite database in the internal memory. Then i am fetching all the data from the database and i want to insert all the data into Google Fusion Table which i have created. i have created one project in google console and enabled the fusion table api. Also i have generated OAuth client_id and api key for my app.

Now I tried to send the insert query through HttpPost. But i am getting 403 error code.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
 }
}
```

This the code snipet.

```
public void insertService(String query) {
    String url = URL + "?sql=" + query + "&key=AIzaSyDD7eZrdhxl7QjTJHgu4thZ-OJZgTOIDXQ";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        // ....
```

There are not enough tutorial or document available for Fusion Table. I have gone through the google documentation but still i have not found any solution.
Should i use OAuth, if so how to use it in java, as it is not clear from the document. If anyone knows please explain me step by step.
Please help me out i need to complete this a quickly as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does you api key have access to fusion tables. I got this error when I didnt have the api configured correctly.